# Date used in SP missing single quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm making an SP and it's my first go with taking a user input.

The purpose of the script is to generate a list of staff that are not on duty. It works, in the sense that the generated list is correct. Though the SP does not

The problem I am having, once I have created it as an SP and then executing it, an error message arises, which is the result of the date not having the required single quotes around it.

Here is the SP code:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE List_of_Staff @var_shiftdate DATE

    AS

    SELECT DISTINCT

    FirstName,
    LastName,
    Location,
    Grade

    FROM Vw_My_Staff_View

    WHERE Location LIKE 'Hospital_Ward_1'

    AND StaffID NOT IN 

    (SELECT StaffId FROM Tbl_List_of_Shifts WHERE ShiftDate = @var_shiftdate
    AND ShiftType not in ('Day Off', 'TOIL') 
    AND ShiftStatus IN ('Assigned','Redeployed'))

    ORDER BY LastName

    GO
```

The Error message is:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

And the resultant code trying to execute the SP is this - and doesn't have single quotes around the date.

```
    USE [My_Database]
    GO

    DECLARE @return_value int

    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[List_of_Staff]
    @var_shiftdate = 2017-05-05

    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

    GO
```

**I would just like to know what I can do so that the user doesn't need to enter the single quotes around the date when the SP asks for the variable.**

Thanks :)

Comment: And what is the issue with putting single quotes around a literal value in an `exec` statement?  The value should be correct and the single quotes are part of the value.

Comment: If the user interface for your users is to be an SSMS query window (or moral equivalents, such as running an SSMS wizard) then they need to supply the quotes - because there's no way to directly write a date literal in the T-SQL language.

Comment: Is 'Hospital_Ward_1' a pattern (e.g. should it match 'Hospital WardX1'?) or a string literal. If it's a literal change the Like to =. Not answering your question, just an observation of your code.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I don't fully understand the workings of it but I am right clicking on the SP, "Execute Stored Procedure" then it pops up a box and I type the desired date into it. This is when the second code section is generated.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks. Ultimately I intend to connect to an Excel Spreadsheet with the SP as the data source. (I've managed to do this before). Then to use VBA to have a date selector box that will ultimately pass the date through to the SP. So I was trying to get the data right ahead of this basically!

Comment: @GM_NHS_UK - you have chosen poorly. A stored procedure does not, and cannot, "ask" the user to do anything. And if your user is not sufficiently trained to work with SSMS and tsql, then you have chosen the wrong path to providing functionality. A datetime or date literal **MUST** be specified in the appropriate format - SSMS is not designed to be an easy-to-use GUI for an inexperienced user to generate "data".

Comment: @Rachel Ambler Yes to be honest that is lazy coding! I have been testing it on various locations and rather than put in the full names (which are more convoluted than the one i put as example) I just put in the bit that I know is unique :) Thanks though, for the final version I will make it exact.

Comment: @SMor Thanks for your comment. I agree re: SSMS, the user won't be using SSMS. The user will have an Excel Spreadsheet that connects to the SP as a data source, with permissions to run just that SP. I already have a similar script working in this capacity, but in Excel when prompted for the Date variable, the quotes must be entered. This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

error exists here 
date should be in single quotes

```
USE [My_Database]
        GO
    Create table #temp(value int)

    insert into #temp
    EXEC [dbo].[List_of_Staff] '2017-05-05'

    SELECT * from #temp
    drop table #temp

    GO
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi, yes that's what I am trying to achieve. But that date is being passed into the Exec statement when I right click the SP and select Execute.